# integrating boost with numerical recipes 3 code

Tags: c++, boost, numerical-methods

i get a bunch of errors when i use both nr3.h and boost library.

I use ubuntu 10.04 with libboost1.40 and code from http://www.nr.com/ (3rd edition)

try.cc:

```
#include "nr3.h"
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

i compile the code "g++ try.cc" and i get errors. if i comment out either the nr3.h line or the < boost ... > line, the code compiles fine.

here are the errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/assert.hpp:36,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/iterator_range.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/as_literal.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp:19,
                 from boostnrexample.cc:2:
/usr/include/assert.h: In function ‘void __assert_fail(const char*, const char*, unsigned int, const char*)’:
/usr/include/assert.h:73: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/assert.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/assert.h:73: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/assert.h: In function ‘void __assert_perror_fail(int, const char*, unsigned int, const char*)’:
/usr/include/assert.h:79: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/assert.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/assert.h:79: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/assert.h: In function ‘void __assert(const char*, const char*, int)’:
/usr/include/assert.h:85: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/assert.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/assert.h:85: error: declaration does not declare anything
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/messages_members.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/locale_facets_nonio.h:1905,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/compare.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp:22,
                 from boostnrexample.cc:2:
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* gettext(const char*)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/libintl.h:41: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* dgettext(const char*, const char*)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/libintl.h:46: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* __dgettext(const char*, const char*)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:48: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/libintl.h:48: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* dcgettext(const char*, const char*, int)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:54: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/libintl.h:54: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* __dcgettext(const char*, const char*, int)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:57: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/libintl.h:57: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* ngettext(const char*, const char*, long unsigned int)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:64: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/libintl.h:64: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* dngettext(const char*, const char*, const char*, long unsigned int)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:70: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/libintl.h:70: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* dcngettext(const char*, const char*, const char*, long unsigned int, int)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:77: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/libintl.h:77: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* textdomain(const char*)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:83: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* bindtextdomain(const char*, const char*)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:88: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/libintl.h: In function ‘char* bind_textdomain_codeset(const char*, const char*)’:
/usr/include/libintl.h:93: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
```

Update:
i also posted it at nr.com forum (http://www.nr.com/forum/showthread.php?t=2148). and got a response that the problem is that nr3.h made a define macro for throw(). i'm still not sure what could be a robust solution.

Comment: Looks like conflicting definition of macro. Try including `nh3.h` *after* all boost and system headers.

Comment: hm, it worked :-)  i replaced the two include lines. however it doesn't seem to be a robust solution. in some case boost might have to be included after nr3.h

Comment: The only robust solution is to get NR upstream change their code to stop defining C++ keywords as macros and start using proper library prefixes instead. It might be a backward compatibility problem though in which case there is really no good solution.

Comment: Also I'd recommend against using NR code straight from the book for anything production related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is to go into nr3.h and change the C++ keyword abusing macro "throw" to an inoffensive none C++ keyword such as "toss".